# Derby DB last x row average

Tags: sql, derby, window-functions

I have the following table structure.

```
   ITEM                  TOTAL
-----------         -----------------
ID  |  TITLE        ID  |ITEMID|VALUE
 1       A          1      2      6
 2       B          2      1      4
 3       C          3      3      3
 4       D          4      3      8
 5       E          5      1      2
 6       F          6      5      4
                    7      4      5
                    8      2      8
                    9      2      7
                    10     1      3
                    11     2      2
                    12     3      6
```

I am using Apache Derby DB. I need to perform the average calculation in SQL. I need to show the list of item IDs and their average total of the last 3 records.
That is, for ITEM.ID 1, I will go to TOTAL table and select the last 3 records of the rows which are associated with the ITEMID 1. And take average of them. In Derby database, I am able to do this for a given item ID but I cannot make it without giving a specific ID. Let me show you what I've done it.

```
SELECT ITEM.ID, AVG(VALUE) FROM ITEM, TOTAL WHERE TOTAL.ITEMID = ITEM.ID GROUP BY ITEM.ID
```

This SQL gives the average of all items in a list. But this calculates for all values of the total tables. I need last 3 records only. So I changed the SQL to this:

```
SELECT AVG(VALUE) FROM (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS ROWNUM, TOTAL.* FROM TOTAL WHERE ITEMID = 1) AS TR WHERE ROWNUM > (SELECT COUNT(ID) FROM TOTAL WHERE ITEMID = 1) - 3
```

This works if I supply the item ID 1 or 2 etc. But I cannot do this for all items without giving an item ID.

I tried to do the same thing in ORACLE using partition and it worked. But derby does not support partitioning. There is WINDOW but I could not make use of it.

Oracle one

```
SELECT ITEMID, AVG(VALUE) FROM(SELECT ITEMID, VALUE, COUNT(*) OVER (PARTITION BY ITEMID) QTY, ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY ITEMID ORDER BY ID) IDX FROM TOTAL ORDER BY ITEMID, ID) WHERE IDX > QTY -3 GROUP BY ITEMID ORDER BY ITEMID
```

I need to use derby DB for its portability.

The desired output is this

```
     RESULT
-----------------
ITEMID  |  AVERAGE
  1         (9/3)
  2         (17/3)
  3         (17/3)
  4         (5/1)
  5         (4/1)
  6          NULL
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you have noticed, Derby's support for the SQL 2003 "OLAP Operations" support is incomplete.

There was some initial work (see https://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/OLAPOperations), but that work was only partially completed.

I don't believe anyone is currently working on adding more functionality to Derby in this area.

So yes, Derby has a `row_number` function, but no, Derby does not (currently) have `partition by`.

Comment: Does that mean there is no other way performing this operation in Derby at the moment?